# RLC series circuit with initial current

Tags: voltage, capacitor, resistors, inductor, passive-networks

I'm trying to solve, for the voltage across the capacitor in the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr32bp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The initial current in this circuit is equal to \$\text{I}_0\$. How can I find the voltage across the capacitor?

> EDIT: The initial applied current is equal to \$\text{I}_0\$, the initial voltage across the capacitor is equal to \$\text{V}_\text{C}\left(0\right)\$ and the initial current trough the inductor is equal to \$\text{I}_\text{L}\left(0\right)\$

**My Work:**

I thought that I can write:

$$\text{V}_{\text{R}_1}\left(t\right)+\text{V}_{\text{R}_2}\left(t\right)+\text{V}_\text{C}\left(t\right)+\text{V}_\text{L}\left(t\right)=0\tag1$$

Writing that in terms of the current through the components I get:

$$\text{I}_\text{in}'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{R}_1+\text{I}_\text{in}'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{R}_2+\text{I}_\text{in}\left(t\right)\cdot\frac{1}{\text{C}}+\text{I}_\text{in}''\left(t\right)\cdot\text{L}=0\tag2$$

And then using the initial conditions \$\text{I}_\text{in}\left(0\right)=\text{I}_0\$ and \$\text{I}_\text{in}'\left(0\right)=0\$ I can solve for the voltage across the capacitor. Is that right?

Comment: Is current \$I_0\$ supplied from a current source and was the current through the inductor prior to t=0 zero amps AND, was the voltage across the capacitor 0 volts at t=0? In other words you need to clearly state your initial condictions. At the moment there is ambiguity.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes only the intial current was supplied.

Comment: That does not answer what I asked.

Comment: @Andyaka I did not read it the right way I think. The intial applied current is equal to \$\text{I}_0\$, the intial voltage across the capacitor is equal to \$\text{V}_\text{C}\left(0\right)\$ and the intial current trough the inductor is equal to \$\text{I}_\text{L}\left(0\right)\$. I also edited that in my question.

Comment: @Klopjas You ***must*** have the initial conditions for the state of the capacitor and the inductor. Given only the value of \$I_0\$ I believe there is more than one possible pairing of initial conditions for the capacitor and inductor.

Comment: @jonk I edited my question.

Comment: @Klopjas then all that remains for you to clarify is the source of that external current because that source type dictates what happens after t=0.

Comment: @Andyaka The source is turned of, but it was a current source but it turns to zero because it is removed.

Comment: If it turns off at t=0 then saying that the initial condition of Vc = 0 is wrong and it is also wrong to say that the initial condition of the inductor current is zero. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: @Andyaka No I stated in my question that those are NOT equal to zero.

Comment: OK I misread what you said but to answer my comment by saying that the initial current through the inductor is \$I_L(0)\$ is like saying that the initial current *IS* the initial current.